# How do I upload a 'Document' sobject using the REST API?

Tags: rest-api, upload

Given a folder ID, I wanted to be able to 'upload' an sObject of type 'Document' from within my code to the salesforce instance for the authenticated user.

I was going through the api reference, but, couldn't find anything.

Pointers will be useful.

Answer (score 7):

There isn't anything specific to Documents.  They're treated just like any other sObject, so post to that objects endpoint, i.e.

```
/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Document/
```

And include pass a json representation of the object.  Note you'll need to base64 encode the body (not shown in example).

```
{
    "folderid": "00l50000000thwt",
    "body": "hello world",
    "name": "testdoc"
}
```